# Concurency issue with SELECT FOR UPDATE in Postgres 9.3

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, thread-safety

I'm struggling with this issue since two days. We have a solution where multiple worker threads will try to select job requests from a single database/table, by setting a flag on the selected requests and thus effectively blocking the other workers to select the same requests.

I created a java test application to test my queries, but while in normal situations the test executes without issue, in high contention situation (ex. 1 table entry with 50 threads; no delays or processing) I still have threads which obtain the same request/entry, interestingly it happens when the test just starts. I cannot understand why. I've read all relevant Postgres locking and isolation related documentation... While is possible that the issue is with the test application itself, I suspect that I'm missing something about how the SELECT FOR UPDATE works in READ COMMITTED isolation context.

So the question would be can SELECT FOR UPDATE (with READ COMMITED isolation) guarantee that a general concurrency issue like I described can be safely solved?

Acquire query:

```
UPDATE mytable SET status = 'LOCK'
  WHERE ctid IN (SELECT ctid FROM mytable
    WHERE status = 'FREE'
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT %d
    FOR UPDATE)
  RETURNING id, status;
```

Release query:

```
UPDATE mytable SET status = 'FREE'
  WHERE id = %d AND status = 'LOCK'
  RETURNING id, status;
```

So would you consider these two queries should be safe, or there is some weird case possible that would allow two threads to acquire the same row? I'd like to mention that I tried also SERIALIZABLE isolation and didn't helped.

Comment: The query contains `LIMIT %d` clause with a parameter - how many rows does the query uptates at once, 1 or more ?

Comment: Don't use ctid, it is not the same thing as a primary key.  I use almost exactly the same construct, but with a primary key instead of ctid, and I've never had a problem with redundant values

Comment: I don't *see* how they're returning the same row, and a forced race test here doesn't show that. Perhaps you should post the full example in runnable form. That said, jjanes is right that you shouldn't be using ctid, it's an internal system col. Also, if a worker dies, how do you tell what row(s) it had and release them back for processing? Consider *not* rolling your own task queue system, and instead using an off the shelf task queue.

Comment: Also: Does the overlap happen in the limit-1 case? Or only for limit values greater than one? And if you add a `WHERE status = 'FREE'` clause to the outer update as well (i.e. you recheck the condition), does that resolve the issue? I can't immediately verify if `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` rechecks quals after unblocking on a lock, though my testing here suggests it does.

Comment: I was using LIMIT 1 in one test, but tried also LIMIT 2 in another test case. Concluded this is not the issue.
I also tried directly with id as primary key as Craig suggested. Concluded this is not the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out (how could it be different?) that I made a mistake in my test. I didn't respected resource acquire/release order. The test was registering the release (decrementing a counter) **after** the Release Query, which lead another thread to Acquire the resource and register it in the meantime. An error from the category, which you know how to solve, but cannot see even if you look several times, because you wrote the code... Peer review helped in the end.

I suppose at this time I have a test to prove that:

1. The above two queries **are safe**
2. You don't need SERIALIZABLE isolation to solve problems with DB acquire/release as long as you use row locking as in SELECT... FOR UPDATE
3. You must ORDER (BY) results when using row locking (even if you use LIMIT 1!), otherwise you end up with deadlocks
4. Safe to acquire multiple resources with one query (LIMIT 2 and above)
5. Using ctid in the query is safe; it's actually a little faster, but this is insignificant in real world applications

I'm not sure if this will be helpful to others, but I was getting desperate. So all is good with Postgres 9.3 :)

Answer (score 1):

Another aspect I'd like so share is regarding the speed of the Acquire query with LIMIT 2. See the test result:

```
Starting test...
DB setup done
All threads created & connections made
All threads started
Thread[36] 186/190/624=1000
Thread[19] 184/201/615=1000
Thread[12] 230/211/559=1000
Thread[46] 175/200/625=1000
Thread[ 9] 205/211/584=1000
...
Thread[ 4] 189/232/579=1000
Thread[ 3] 185/198/617=1000
Thread[49] 218/204/578=1000
Thread[ 1] 204/203/593=1000
...
Thread[37] 177/163/660=1000
Thread[31] 168/199/633=1000
Thread[18] 174/187/639=1000
Thread[42] 178/229/593=1000
Thread[29] 201/229/570=1000
...
Thread[10] 203/198/599=1000
Thread[25] 215/210/575=1000
Thread[27] 248/191/561=1000
...
Thread[17] 311/192/497=1000
Thread[ 8] 365/198/437=1000
Thread[15] 389/176/435=1000
All threads finished
Execution time: 31408
Test done; exiting
```

Compare the above with this query :

```
UPDATE mytable SET status = 'LOCK'
  WHERE id IN (SELECT t1.id FROM (SELECT id FROM mytable 
      WHERE status = 'FREE' ORDER BY id LIMIT 2) AS t1
    FOR UPDATE)
  RETURNING id, status;
```

and the result:

```
Starting test...
DB setup done
All threads created & connections made
All threads started
Thread[29] 32/121/847=1000
Thread[22] 61/151/788=1000
Thread[46] 36/114/850=1000
Thread[41] 57/132/811=1000
Thread[24] 49/146/805=1000
Thread[13] 47/135/818=1000
...
Thread[20] 48/118/834=1000
Thread[47] 65/152/783=1000
Thread[18] 51/146/803=1000
Thread[ 8] 69/158/773=1000
Thread[14] 56/158/786=1000
Thread[ 0] 66/161/773=1000
Thread[38] 60/148/792=1000
Thread[27] 69/158/773=1000
...
Thread[45] 78/177/745=1000
Thread[30] 96/162/742=1000
...
Thread[32] 162/167/671=1000
Thread[17] 329/156/515=1000
Thread[33] 337/178/485=1000
Thread[37] 381/172/447=1000
All threads finished
Execution time: 15490
Test done; exiting
```

### Conclusion

The test prints for each thread how many times the Acquire query returned 2, 1 or 0 resources totalling the number of test loops (1000).

From the above results we can conclude that we can speed up the query (halfing the time!) at the cost of increasing the thread contention. This means that we will receive more times 0 resources back from the Acquire query. Technically this is not a problem because we need to treat this situation anyway.

Of course situation changes if you add a wait time (sleeping) when no resources are returned, but choosing a correct value for the wait time depends on the application performance requirements...